# Python: superimposing and smoothing graphics

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 100 different graphics, they looks like
[image: first][image: second]

I need to superimpose all of them and next smooth result.
I try this

```
import Image

first = Image.open("test1.png")
second = Image.open("test2.png")

first.paste(second, (0, 0), second)
first.show()
```

But how can I do it to 100 graphics? And how can I smooth result?
First 10 steps in dataframe looks like

```
       active nodes
graph              
0              1024
1               598
2               349
3               706
4               541
5               623
6               576
7               614
8               578
9               613
10              595
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by smooth?

Comment: @Petar I need to get average curve from all this graphics

Comment: If you don't have the data you won't be able to do this.

Comment: @Peter I can get data. How can I do that with data?

Comment: You will have to show a sample of the data in your question for anyone to answer that.

Comment: @Petar I have written a part of dataframe. It's first 10 steps

Comment: Shouldn't the dataframe you mention contain the number of steps, `n`, too? To "smoothen" the results, we need to obtain the average number of nodes at each `n` for each graph, no?

Comment: We still would need some more data to answer the question I think. Can you just take the average of each pixel?

Answer (score 1):

You have it just as an image, or you also have the data that makes the graph? 
If you have the data, the easiest way to smooth it is to use `convolution`.

```
n=100
smoothed_data=np.convolve(data,[1/n]*n,'same')
```

Comment: I have only images